# ImageView objects go out of bounds from screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a StartActivity which has a play button, when pressed it takes you to the MainActivty where there are 9 ImageView objects which are set to the bitmap img "aliencreature" as you will see in my xml file below. The imageview objects are to be set to random positions on startup i used display metrics and random to do this however my first problem is that they are out of bounds at times. Not all 9 imageviews show in the screen and sometimes half an imageview is shown and even if all do show up 1 or two are imageviews get smaller for some reason. I've attached my .java and xml file please tell me if you need me to be more detailed in my question.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tapoo.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"

>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"  />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="147dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
     tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="740dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/restartButton"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/restartbutton"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countDownTimer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Seconds remaining: 10"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scoreNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="19sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="188dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:src="@drawable/aliencreature"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final Intent intent = getIntent();

setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
counter = 0;
score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreNumber);
countDownTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownTimer);
view1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
view3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
view4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
view5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
view6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
view7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
view8 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
view9 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);




allImages = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
allImages.add(view1);
allImages.add(view2);
allImages.add(view3);
allImages.add(view4);
allImages.add(view5);
allImages.add(view6);
allImages.add(view7);
allImages.add(view8);
allImages.add(view9);










for(final ImageView views : allImages){ //allimages is an arraylist of imageviews that contains my 9 imageviews



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) views.getLayoutParams();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels ;


    Random r = new Random();

    params.leftMargin =  r.nextInt(width-48)  ; // 48 is the width of my bitmap img
    params.topMargin =  r.nextInt(height-50)  ; //50 is the height of my bitmap img
    views.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your value in the file /value/dimen of your project you will find that hte following

```
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

are not null. So due to your RelativeLayout definition in your main layout you will find that the drawable area is smaller than the entire screen so

```
    params.leftMargin =  r.nextInt(width-48)  ; // 48 is the width of my bitmap img
    params.topMargin =  r.nextInt(height-50)
```

won't be sufficient.
My suggestion is to remove the padding definition in your RelativeLayout, like this your images will always be on the screen.

Second thing, remove in your ImageView definition

```
   tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
```

After these corrections everything would be fine;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i go to /value/dimen this is all i see <resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

</resources>

Comment: Never mind i found it in my fragment main it works, thank you!